# UDP socket fails to receive data

Tags: python, sockets, udp, lan, plc

I've a problem: I created a small Python script to read data from an Omron PLC memory on LAN. Delphi program run batch file that run Python script periodically (every 6 seconds).

This script runs on 2 Win 7 PCs and 1 Win XP PC.

My problem is: no data transfer between Win XP PC and PLC for a random period of time (around 1 minute, sometimes more), but Win 7 PCs have no problem to communicate with same PLC.

I use UDP protocol.

```
def main():
    udpSock = util_socket.utilSocket()
    command = udpSock.read_from_file("udpCommand")
    command = int(command)
    messaggio = mex()
    if command==1:
        msg = messaggio.get_messaggio_lettura()
        udpSock.send_command(msg)
        ricevi_risposta(udpSock)
    if command==2:
        msg = messaggio.get_messaggio_azzeramento()
        udpSock.send_command(msg)
        msg = messaggio.get_messaggio_lettura()
        udpSock.send_command(msg)
        ricevi_risposta(udpSock)
    if command<1 or command>2:
        udpSock.write_to_file("ERROR !!!", "numPezzi")

def ricevi_risposta(udpSock):        
    data, addr = udpSock.recv_socket()
    contaPezzi = udpSock.get_dato_pulito(data)
    udpSock.write_to_file(contaPezzi, "numPezzi")
    stringa = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime( "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" )) + " - dato ricevuto: " + str(data) + " // dato convertito: " + str(contaPezzi) + "\n" 
    udpSock.append_to_file(stringa, "numPezzi_Log_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime( "%d/%m/%Y")) )

def recv_socket(self):

    # the public network interface
    #HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

    # create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
    self.get_parametri()
    s.bind((self.ipAddressPc, 0))
    # Include IP headers
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(65536)

    return data, addr

def send_command(self, msg):
    self.get_parametri()
    udp_ip = self.ipAddressPlc
    udp_port=9600 #5575

    #print "UDP target IP:", udp_ip
    #print "UDP target port:", udp_port
    #print "message:", msg

    sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                          socket.SOCK_DGRAM ) # UDP
    sock.sendto( msg, (udp_ip, udp_port) )
```

LAN seems "fall to sleep". This is LOG File: (08:41:13 -> 08:42:30. Expectation 08:41:13 -> 08:41:19, 08:41:25, 08:41:31, ...)

```
27/03/2013 08:41:13 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 252
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:30 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 260
27/03/2013 08:42:36 - dato ricevuto (dati non riportabili) dato convertito: 261
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to network congestion in your LAN. If it is just happening for a little while like 1 minute.

Comment: it's not possible because i can ping Win XP pc and watch it with ultraVNC and other softwares.

Comment: @Supremenerd88 - ping and VNC work over TCP, not UDP.  UDP is much more vulnerable to errors and dropped packets, especially over congested networks and in electrically noisy environments.  UDP offers no guarantee that the packets get delivered or that they get delivered correctly.  When using UDP you must check and re-request yourself if the communication does not succeed. see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Reliability_and_congestion_control_solutions